# Select tag : How to use params to set the selected value?

Tags: ruby, html-select, ruby-on-rails-5, dropdown

I have a select tag with 2 options :

```
 select_tag :type,  options_for_select("<option value = 'produit1'>Produit1</option><option value = 'Produit2'>Produit2</option>", params[:product]), id: "different_option_value_html", onchange: "this.form.submit();", include_blank: "Which products ?"
```

When one of this options are selected, the form is automatically submit. I would like to keep the params in first position. I mean visible without clicking on the select, at the place of "which products".

Comment: `include_blank: params[:product]`?

Comment: I already tried this option, it seems the more obvious to me, but it displayed nothing at all.

Comment: may be because params[:product] is `nil` or empty string?

Comment: I don't think because the param is present in the url, and the products are well filtered

Comment: just check what's in `params[:product]`, maybe you want `params[:product][:name]` or something. Debug the value of `params[:product]` and make sure it is there

Comment: When I use pry to debug I get : params[:product] = "produit1"

Comment: then it should work just fine. may be add explicit braces `{ include_blank: params[:product] }`

Comment: Yeah that was it ! The only problems is that "which products?" completely disapear and my list look like : "product1, product1, product2" OR "product2, product2, product1". The selected product appear both instead of just being selected

Comment: I'll upvote for your comment for sure. But it's not exactly the answer, see my comment below :)

Comment: `select_tag :type,  options_for_select("<option value = 'produit1'>Produit1</option><option value = 'Produit2'>Produit2</option>", params[:product], selected: params[:product]), id: "different_option_value_html", onchange: "this.form.submit();", include_blank: "Which products?"`

Comment: >> wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally change the syntax and it works fine using :`options_for_select(:collection, :selected)`

So there is my code now :

```
= select_tag :product,  options_for_select(["Product1", "Product2"], params[:product]), id: "different_option_value_html", onchange: "this.form.submit();", include_blank: "Which product ?"
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. Browsed over 10 questions and resources before coming across your answer!